# Inconsistent window styles behavior when trying to disable window resizing in win 32

Tags: c++, wpf, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I have the following styles applied to my window and I can resize which is expected (WS_CAPTION, WS_VISIBLE, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_SYSMENU, WS_THICKFRAME, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, WS_MINIMIZEBOX). My aim is to remove WS_SYSMENU and disable resizing.

So I then remove WS_THICKFRAME and window resizing is disabled as expected. I then have to also remove WS_SYSMENU as well but window resizing comes back.

My final set of styles are (WS_CAPTION, WS_VISIBLE, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, WS_MINIMIZEBOX).

Anyone know why this is happening please?

Comment: Are you creating a window? Show us your `CreateWindow` call

Comment: Window is a chromeless WPF window created via WPF so I am not calling CreateWindow directly but I did pull out the above styles from Spy++ and want to know which to remove to disable the ability to resize the window.

Comment: Before you went with all the WS_ stuff did you try ResizeMode="NoResize"  in the window tag?

Comment: Yes I did. It does the same thing behind the scenes. Basically it just removes WS_THICKFRAME. Problem is I also need WS_SYSMENU removed which seems to bring back resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine for me on a normal win32 window:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_CAPTION|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX|WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

The final styles are 0x16C30000 and 0x00000100.

Adding `WS_POPUP` often helps when you want to remove the sizing border.

WS_MAXIMIZEBOX and WS_MINIMIZEBOX will not be visible in the caption without WS_SYSMENU. You can [disable the close button](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100604-00/?p=13803) by disabling SC_CLOSE in the system menu if that is what you are after...